# Nuget showing error + mono

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, nuget

I installed mono and monodevelop in my linux system. Also i created a project as ASP.NET WEB API project , in that its throwing error for Assembly missing.

```
using System.Web.Http; -----------------> throwing error here Syste.Web.Http assembly is missing

namespace xxxxxx
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void  Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

In my project folder under references folder only System.Web is there but not System.Web.Http. SO i tried to add using "NUget Packages". But its showing error `"object reference not set to an instance of an object, Cannot make secure connection"`.

As i am very new bee to .NET and mono, i cant able to figure it out. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

I am using

```
Mono version:  5.0.1.1
MonoDevelop version:7.0.1
```

Comment: Where is that object reference shown? In the Package Console? If it is from the Package Console then it sounds like you may be hitting this bug in Mono - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57019 There is a workaround discussed in that bug.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a mistake under the proxy..

If you started new, I suggest you use vscode instead of mono. You can develop .net core applications.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aY4Rhmv5P_Q

Comment: Thanks.. I am looking for this for past 1 day. So its better if you guide me to crack in this monoDevelop..